# JQuery UI, Jquery touch punch and JQuery tools conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tools

I use all libraries in the tittle. I want to use Jquery tools to get this: http://jquerytools.org/documentation/rangeinput/index.html and touch punch to simulate mobile events. Together those two libraries fail to work.

How to include and use this two libraries not to cause conflicts ?

Example of use are below:

Use of touch punch:

```
$(thumb).draggable({});
```

Use of JQuery tools:

```
$(":range").rangeinput();
```

For  some strange reason if I use range tools from JQuery tools my dragging implementation fails :S

Comment: Don't use jQuery Tools, use jQuery UI. You will save yourself a world of hurt.

Comment: I have a very odd problem which forced me to use the tools :(

Comment: then let's fix your problem, because I really doubt that anyone NEEDS to use that awful library.

Comment: I need a vertical slider! The tools slider is better then the Jquery UI slider ....

Comment: [jQuery UI has a vertical slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#slider-vertical)

Comment: Regarding "better," it may seem more robust out of the box, but the jQUI will be easier to extend and manipulate. (I'm obviously very biased.)

Comment: The Jquery Ui slider is giving me problems with its handle. It has stupid positioning. Jquery tools sliders handle is always to the dge og the content....